# Header not filling the entire width or top of the body

Tags: html, css

Random question I am running into that I am sure is a dull oversign on my part.  My header isn't filling to the top portion or left/right portions of my screennand leaving the body a little bit of room in those areas.  I provded padding and margins for the elements inside the header, but have tried to max the header size to no avail.  Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    boz-sizing: border-box;
}

body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #5F5E5E;
}

/***************
HEADING
****************/

 header{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 -60px 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
   }

#logo {
 margin: 5px 0 0 70px;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the default `margins` setting by browsers:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/00nosjbp/)

Note: Also `boz-sizing` should be `box-sizing` ;)